# Expensive subquery tuning with SQLite

Tags: performance, sqlite

I'm working on a small media/file management utility using sqlite for it's persistent storage needs. I have a table of files:

```sql
CREATE TABLE file
  ( file_id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  , file_sha1     BINARY(20)
  , file_name     TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
  , file_size     INTEGER NOT NULL
  , file_mime     TEXT NOT NULL
  , file_add_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  );
```

And also a table of albums

```sql
CREATE TABLE album
  ( album_id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  , album_name    TEXT
  , album_poster  INTEGER
  , album_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  , FOREIGN KEY (album_poster) REFERENCES file(file_id)
  );
```

to which files can be assigned

```sql
CREATE TABLE album_file
  ( album_id  INTEGER NOT NULL
  , file_id   INTEGER NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (album_id, file_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(album_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES file(file_id)
  );

CREATE INDEX file_to_album ON album_file(file_id, album_id);
```

Part of the functionality is to list albums, exposing

- the album id,
- the album's name,
- an poster image for that album and
- the number of files in the album

which currently uses this query:

```sql
SELECT a.album_id, a.album_name, 
  COALESCE(
    a.album_poster,
    (SELECT file_id FROM file
     NATURAL JOIN album_file af
     WHERE af.album_id = a.album_id
     ORDER BY file.file_name LIMIT 1)),
  (SELECT COUNT(file_id) AS file_count
   FROM album_file WHERE album_id = a.album_id)
FROM album a
ORDER BY album_name ASC
```

The only "tricky" part of that query is that the album_poster column may be null, in which case `COALESCE` statement is used to just return the first file in the album as the "default poster".

With currently ~260000 files, ~2600 albums and ~250000 entries in the album_file table, this query takes over 10 seconds which makes for a not-so-great user experience. Here's the query plan:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE album AS a
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|1|SEARCH TABLE album_file AS af USING COVERING INDEX album_to_file (album_id=?)
1|1|0|SEARCH TABLE file USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
1|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
2|0|0|SEARCH TABLE album_file USING COVERING INDEX album_to_file (album_id=?)
```

Replacing the `COALESCE` statement with just `a.album_poster`, sacrificing the auto-poster functionality, brings the query time down to a few milliseconds:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE album AS a
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE album_file USING COVERING INDEX album_to_file (album_id=?)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

What I don't understand is that limiting the album listing to 1 or 1000 rows makes no difference. It seems SQLite is doing the expensive sub-query for the "default" poster on all albums, only to throw away most of the results when finally cutting down the result set to the `LIMIT`s specified with the query.

Is there something I can do to make the original query substantially faster, especially given that I'm usually only querying a small subset (using `LIMIT`) of all rows for display?

Comment: Without an index on the ORDER BY column, the database has to compute all columns because the last one might have the smallest value. And can't you make "first file" mean "the file with the smallest ID"? And can't you execute the subquery manually later when you see that the poster is NULL?

Comment: @CL. Adding an index on the album_name column really did magic, I assume that's because now the expensive sub-query is executed only for the rows that are going to be returned. otoh, the "smallest ID" trick seems not so nice, because that could be quite confusing for the user. You might want to turn your comment into an answer for extra karma. :-)

Comment: Too lazy; answer it yourself. :o)